# Ansible string concat before filter

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I was having an issue in my Ansible template where I wanted to create an HTTP basic auth credential out of two different variables a user inputs into the play.

The first thing I tried to do was:

```
basic_auth: "{{ user + ':' + pass | b64encode }}"
```

However I ended up with:

```
basic_auth: "user:<BASE64_ENCODED>"
```

How can I have Jinja concatenate these strings and then pass it through my filter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty basic solution: group with parenthesis.

```
basic_auth: "{{ (user + ':' + pass) | b64encode }}"
```

I assume that this will allow me to nest several layers of filters.

```
complex: "{{ ((user + ':' + pass) | b64encode) | complex_filter}}"
```